# onCreate() method should not call

Tags: android

When my application's orientation change every time onCreate() method call.
It makes me difficult to handle GUI in Activity.

can I avoid onCreate() method one Activity has been created and started?

I don't want to make screen as static as portrait or landscape

is there any way to avoid onCreate() method?

Thank You.

Comment: you can avoid it by not developing in Android :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may get mixed responses, but the best I've been able to find is by adding `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` to your activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<activity
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:name=".ActivityName">
```

[There are other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android).

**Note: If you mean you never want it called, then no, it has to be called.**

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. Dalvik will hate you if don't call the super.onCreate() and will throw you a mean SuperNotCalledException.